# Regex sub-expression matching with Find + emacs-regex mode

Tags: regex, emacs, find

I'm trying to find some compressed log files, and do some operations on them. I can't use ls because they are thousands of files in the directory and BASH throws a 'argument list too long' error. 
This has brought me to find, but I'm having trouble with my regex.

Here is the whole find command

```
find $i -regex '.*logfile_MP[0-9]-GW0[0-9]_2010-09-\(\([7-9]\)|\(1[0-9]\)|\(2[0-3]\)\)-.*' -exec ls {} \;
```

I actually need to go through several log directories, so $i comes from a BASH loop to go through all the directories.
Right now, I'm just trying to list the files, so I know I have the right ones; I'll amend my -exec statement once I get it working.

The problem relates to the parentheses section:

```
\(\([7-9]\)|\(1[0-9]\)|\(2[0-3]\)\)
```

I'm trying to match a range of days (7-23). From what I understand about Emacs-regex mode, I have to escape all parentheses. 
The rest of the regex is working because if I replace the parentheses section with just a number (ex. 7), it works fine.

Can anyone help me create a regex sub-expression to match 7-23?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, just missing a `\` in front of each of the `|`:

```
\([7-9]\|1[0-9]\|2[0-3]\)
```

Comment: Thanks Trey. It worked perfectly. That's the ugliest regex I've every used. Stupid escapes...